# Restart react timer from parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a small issue here:

I have two components, a `parent`, and a `timer`, which is one of the children of `parent`

the `parent` passes down to the child a `delay` and a `callback`. The timer will execute the `callback` every `delay` milliseconds.

---

this is the code for the timer:

```
interface TimerProps {
  delayInMilliseconds: number;
  callback: Function;
}

const Timer = (props: TimerProps) => {
  const { delayInMilliseconds, callback } = props;
  const [ timerId, setTimerId ] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    createTimer();
  }, []);

  const createTimer = () => {
      setTimerId(setInterval(callback, delayInMilliseconds))
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  };

  const restartTimer = () => {
    stopTimer();
    createTimer();
  };

  return <button onClick={restartTimer}>stop timer</button>;
};
```

So far, so good. The timer does what id needs to do, and the `restartTimer` function works.

---

What I'm trying do do now is to tie the `restartTimer` function to a button that is present on the `parent` component.

I've tried to use `React.forwardRef` with `React.useImperativeHandle`, but it's not entirely clear to me the mechanism behind it, and so far I haven't had any luck

Could anyone help me understand how to "expose" the child's `restartTimer` function to the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making the functional component a class component, and using useRef to access it from the parent element

child:

```
interface TimerProps {
  delayInMilliseconds: number;
  callback: Function;
}

interface TimerState {
  timerId: number;
}

class Timer extends React.Component<TimerProps, TimerState> {
  constructor(props: TimerProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timerId: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createTimer();
  }

  createTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      timerId: setInterval(this.props.callback, this.props.delayInMilliseconds),
    });
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(this.state.timerId);
  };

  restartTimer = () => {
    this.stopTimer();
    this.createTimer();
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default Timer;
```

parent:

```
  const handleRefreshButtonClick = () => {
    if (timerRef) {
      timerRef?.current?.restartTimer();
    }
  }

  ...

  const timerRef = React.useRef();
  return(
    <Timer
      ref={timerRef}
      delayInMilliseconds={refreshDelay //5000}
      callback={doOtherStuff}/>
  )

  ...

  <Button onClick={handleRefreshButtonClick} />
```

Answer (score -1):

create the state and function in your parent component and pass that to your child component i.e timer component and handle it from your parent component.